# Issue with Price Rules for shopping cart

Tags: promotions, price-rules, product-attribute

[image]Hi I am running two magento websites, different installs on different servers with different themes. Magento version is same for both and that is 1.7.0.2. The problem I am facing is, different price rules options in `Conditions` in `Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules` . In one of the sites,  there are a lot of options(in select field) in `Conditions` for Product Attribute like Attribute set, Category, SKU, Color,  model, price,  special price, visibility, url and lot more. But in other site there are only two options there for Product attribute, and those are Attribute set and Category.

I changed other options like discount action etc but there remains only two options. I do not know whether its any other 3rd party extension(have different extensions in both sites) which are responsible or is there any other configuration options for this somewhere else in Magento.

Any type of help regarding this would be highly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Product Attribute list is populated by the product attributes that you have set up for the store. Additionally each product attribute needs to be enabled to be used in promotions. The setting is in the attribute's Frontend section called "Use for Promo Rule Conditions"

[image]